# How do I create directories named after each month?

Tags: shell-script, xargs, bash-expansion

I would like to create a directory name for each month. I know, after some playing with the shell, that:

```
date -d 1/01 +%b # Gives Jan
date -d 2/01 +%b # Gives Feb
.
date -d 12/01 +%b # Gives Dec
```

So I have used brace expansion, `echo {1..12}/01` and tried to `xargs` it:

```
echo {1..12}/01 | xargs -n 1 -I {} date -d {} +%b
```

But it fails miserably :/ (afterwards I'd like to apply `mkdir`). How can I do this?

Comment: You seem to be over-programming this.  If there's a reason, it would help if you explained why you don't simply write 12 lines, "mkdir "Jan"; mkdir "Feb";...".  If you need to do it multiple times, put the code in a function, and call as needed.

Comment: Why are you naming your directories with the *names* of the months instead of the numbers 01-12?  It's gotta be awkward having them `ls`ed in alphabetical order (Apr, Aug, Dec, Feb, Jan, Jul, Jun, Mar, May, Nov, Oct, Sep).

Comment: @jamesqf Why would you do that when you can simply do *`mkdir january february [...]`* ? Unless you really need to create them separately there is no need to do it the way you suggested.

Comment: @user1024 I would normally agree with you but I have for one use case the name of the months (lower case though); in another I have 01january etc. Who can tell? There are numerous reasons it might or might be better one way or another. (But yes - if sorting is an issue...)

Comment: @Pryftan: Only a personal preference for shorter lines :-)  Also, if I later wanted to change to e.g. "01Jan", it's easier in my editor to do a "c/ / 01/ 12 1" than to do the change on one line.

Comment: @jamesqf Well fair enough. As a long time mate of mine put it when we were collaborating on something in UNIX there are many ways to skin the *`cat`*... Personally I would find one directory an invocation a nightmare - and extra typing too although that's less of an issue for me. Or maybe it's not. I really don't know why - it's probably in part also because I'm used to taking advantage of argc/argv (both in my own code and others). Anyway, whatever works best for you is what matters in the end.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With `-I`, `xargs` gets one argument per line as opposed to the default of one argument per (blank or newline delimited, possibly quoted) word without `-I` (and implies `-n`). So in your example `date` is called only once with `{}` expanded to the whole output of `echo` (which is on one line), minus the trailing newline.

Here you can do (note that that `-d` is a GNU extension):

```
printf '%s\n' {1..12}/01 | xargs -I {} date -d {} +%b | xargs mkdir --
```

(note that it won't work correctly in locales where month name abbreviations contain spaces or quote characters; with GNU `xargs`, you can work around that by using `xargs -d '\n' mkdir --`)

Now, to get the list of month abbreviations in your locale, querying the locale directly would make more sense:

```
(IFS=';'; set -o noglob; mkdir -- $(locale abmon))
```

(see also `locale -k LC_TIME` to see all the locale data in the `LC_TIME` category).

Or natively in `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/langinfo
mkdir -- ${(v)langinfo[(I)ABMON_*]}
```

At least on GNU systems, in some locales, month abbreviations are padded to fixed width with spaces:

```
$ LC_ALL=et_EE.UTF-8 locale title abmon
Estonian locale for Estonia
jaan ;veebr;märts;apr  ;mai  ;juuni;juuli;aug  ;sept ;okt  ;nov  ;dets
$ LC_ALL=zh_TW.UTF-8 locale title abmon
Chinese locale for Taiwan R.O.C.
 1月; 2月; 3月; 4月; 5月; 6月; 7月; 8月; 9月;10月;11月;12月
```

You may want to remove that padding.

The leading spaces would be removed by `xargs -I`, but not the trailing ones. With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/langinfo
set -o extendedglob
mkdir -- ${${${(v)langinfo[(I)ABMON*]}##[[:space:]]#}%%[[:space:]]#}
```

Comment: Nice! Did not know about `locale abmon`.

Comment: Nice answer, but tl;dr : `IFS=';'; set -o noglob; mkdir -- $(locale abmon)`. ;)

Answer (score 9):

Try a loop?

```
$ for m in {1..12}; do
> date -d "$m"/01 +%b
> done
jan
feb
mar
apr
maj
jun
jul
aug
sep
okt
nov
dec
```

If you want to make a directory for each month, I would do something like:

```
for m in {1..12}; do newdir=$(date -d "$m"/01 +%b); mkdir "$newdir"; done
```

Comment: Note that `{1..12}` is a bashism. For a POSIX shell, use `for m in $(seq 1 12)...` (though note that `seq` itself is not mandated by POSIX)

Comment: @RadovanGarabík, technically, `{1..12}` is a zshism, copied later by ksh93, bash and several other shells.

Answer (score 5):

Your command does not work, because of using `-I` changes the delimiter of xargs:

> **-I replace-str**
>   Replace  occurrences  of  replace-str  in  the initial-arguments with names read from standard input.  Also, **unquoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead the separator is the newline character.**

You can add `-d " "` to xargs to make it work. But you don't even need `-I{}` in your case:

Try this,

```
echo {1..12}/01 | xargs -n1 date +%b -d | xargs mkdir
```

Comment: Note that for GNU `date` to accept options after non-option arguments like that, there must not be a  `POSIXLY_CORRECT` variable in the environment.

Answer (score 5):

In shells with brace expansion, and date accepting DATAFILE input, try

```
echo {01..12}/01$'\n' | date -f- +"mkdir %b"
```

and pipe into shell if happy with the result.

Answer (score 3):

You where so so close.

The problem is that echo is producing a single line `1/01 2/01 3/01 4/01 5/01 6/01 7/01 8/01 9/01 10/01 11/01 12/01`, and that xargs is using the newline character as a field separator (not the space).

The solution: Tell echo to put a space between each field.

`echo -e {1..12}/01\\n | xargs -n 1 -I {} date -d {} +%b`

I only inserted `\\n` at the end of the echo.

Then to make the directories add `|xargs mkdir`

e.g.

`echo -e {1..12}/01\\n | xargs -n 1 -I {} date -d {} +%b | xargs  mkdir`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most robust way of doing this:

```
mkdir jan feb mar apr maj jun jul aug sep okt nov dec
```

It's a static list of months after all...

If you are intent on using GNU `date` (here assuming an unmodified `$IFS` and GNU `date` like for your `date -d`):

```
mkdir $( printf '%s\n' {1..12}/01 | date -f - +%b )
```

Comment: Except that it doesn't make month name abbreviations in the language of the user.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Unless they are Swedish, like me :-)